# "variable might not have been initialized" where to initialise with switch case?

Tags: java

Hello I'm new to coding so sorry if this doesn't make sense or is stupid question. 
I want my main function to take arguments from the command line to call certain methods. I'm getting the error `"Variable 'newTree' might not have been initialized"` which I understand (I think) but I don't know how to go about fixing it. I want the newTree object to persist between commands (i.e. if the first command is `init add 1 add 5` and a second command made `add 6` it will add 6 the tree created in the previous command) until the init command is inputted creating a new empty tree. I haven't initialized the instance outside of the init case because I thought it would create a new object everytime the class was called instead of just when init was inputted as an argument? 
Any help with fixing is very appreciated thank you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        switch (args[i]) {
            case "init":
                Tree newTree = new Tree();
                break;
            case "add":
                newTree.add(args[i++]);
                break;
            case "remove":
                newTree.remove();
                break;
            case "show":
                newTree.showTree(root);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running the program once for each command?  Or are  you passing all the commands at once, e.g. `init add 1 add 5 add6`?

Comment: You can move the variable declaration to the top like `Tree newTree = null;` and then you can write `newTree = new Tree();` in your ´case` block for `"init"`. Be careful that you could run in a `NullPointerException` when you go into the other blocks before calling `init`.

Comment: What will the value of `newTree` be if the first command entered is not `"init"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simple: think of what will happen if the user passes as arguments

```
show add 1 add 2 remove
```

---

To fix this, you can either

1. always initialize the tree when the program is run (so there's no need for the `init` command):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Tree newTree = new Tree();

    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        switch (args[i]) {
            case "add":
                newTree.add(args[i++]);
                break;
            case "remove":
                newTree.remove();
                break;
            case "show":
                newTree.showTree(root);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

2. throw an error/do nothing/display a message if the user try to access tree commands without initializing it:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tree newTree = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        switch (args[i]) {
            case "init":
                newTree = new Tree();
                break;
            case "add":
                // Will throw NullPointerException if not initialized
                newTree.add(args[i++]);
                break;
            case "remove":
                // Will throw NullPointerException if not initialized
                newTree.remove();
                break;
            case "show":
                // Will throw NullPointerException if not initialized
                newTree.showTree(root);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you declared newTree twice

Answer (score 2):

simply add an initiation to null. Even if you do this the init case must come up or the app will crash.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //init to null if "init" case isn't called this could crash...
        Tree newTree=null;
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            switch (args[i]) {
                case "init":
                    //it is now declared already
                    newTree = new Tree();
                    break;
                case "add":
                    newTree.add(args[i++]);
                    break;
                case "remove":
                    newTree.remove();
                    break;
                case "show":
                    newTree.showTree(root);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```